# Remove Redundant Parenthesis in an Arithmetic Expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tree, traversal

I'm trying to remove redundant parentheses from an arithmetic expression. For example, if I have the expression `(5+((2*3)))`, I want the redundant parenthesis between `(2*3)` removed. The output that I want is `(5+(2*3))`.

I'm getting this arithmetic expression from performing an inorder traversal on an expression tree. The final string that I get after performing the traversal is `((5)+(((2)*(3))))`. I used `re.sub('\((\d+)\)', r'\1', <traversal output string>)` to remove the parenthesis between the numbers like `(5)` to `5`. But I'm still confused on how I should approach to remove parenthesis among sub expressions (`((2*3))` in this case).

Here is what my inorder traversal function looks like

```
    def inorder(tree):
        # return string of inorder traversal of tree with parenthesis
        s = ''
        if tree != None:
            s += '('
            s += ExpTree.inorder(tree.getLeftChild())
            s += str(tree.getRootVal())
            s += ExpTree.inorder(tree.getRightChild())
            s += ')'

        return re.sub('\((\d+)\)', r'\1', s)
```

Any guidance on how I should approach to solve this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the parenthesis around the parent/root expression, one option is to add the parentheses before and after recursing down on each of the left and right children. If those children are leaves, meaning they do not have children, do not add parentheses.

In practice, this might look something like this:

```
def inorder(tree):
    # return string of inorder traversal of tree with parenthesis
    s = ''
    # Add left subtree, with parentheses if it is not a leaf
    left = tree.getLeftChild()
    if left is not None:
        if left.isLeaf():
            s += ExpTree.inorder(left)
        else:
            s += '(' + ExpTree.inorder(left) + ')'

    # Add root value
    s += str(tree.getRootVal())

    # Add right subtree, with parentheses if it is not a leaf
    right = tree.getRightChild()
    if right is not None:
        if right.isLeaf():
            s += ExpTree.inorder(right)
            else:
                s += '(' + ExpTree.inorder(right) + ')'
    return s
```

This means that a tree with a single node, 5, will become just `"5"`, and the following tree

```
  +
 / \
5   *
   / \
  2   3
```

will become `"5+(2*3)"`.

To instead get the output `"(5+((2*3)))"`, add an additional set of parenthesis around the returned string if the tree is not a leaf.

```
def inorder(tree):
    # return string of inorder traversal of tree with parenthesis
    s = ''
    # Add left subtree, with parentheses if it is not a leaf
    left = tree.getLeftChild()
    if left is not None:
        if left.isLeaf():
            s += ExpTree.inorder(left)
        else:
            s += '(' + ExpTree.inorder(left) + ')'

    # Add root value
    s += str(tree.getRootVal())

    # Add right subtree, with parentheses if it is not a leaf
    right = tree.getRightChild()
    if right is not None:
        if right.isLeaf():
            s += ExpTree.inorder(right)
            else:
                s += '(' + ExpTree.inorder(right) + ')'

    # Add an additional set of parenthesis around non-leaf expressions.
    if tree.isLeaf():
        return s
    else:
        return '(' + s + ')'
```

Comment: Your solution makes sense but how would I terminate `.isLeaf()` when it reaches the leaf and the node is `NoneType`?

Comment: One option is to check for None first in the conditions—I've added that to the answer. This would also mean that you don't have to check if the root tree is None initially, since you will not recurse on a child of None. In other words, the base case of the recursion is when the expression tree is a leaf, rather than when the expression tree is None.